# PrimeFaces DataTable LazyLoading unknown number of records

Tags: datatable, primefaces, numbers, lazy-loading

I am developing PrimeFaces datatable with pagination and lazy data model (number of records to load into datatable is unknown). I have run into problem with pagination. In example from PrimeFaces tutorial lazydatatable with pagination looks like this:

```
@Override  
public List<Car> load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String,String> filters) {  
    List<Car> data = new ArrayList<Car>();  

    //filter  
    for(Car car : datasource) {  
        boolean match = true;  

        for(Iterator<String> it = filters.keySet().iterator(); it.hasNext();) {  
            try {  
                String filterProperty = it.next();  
                String filterValue = filters.get(filterProperty);  
                String fieldValue = String.valueOf(car.getClass().getField(filterProperty).get(car));  

                if(filterValue == null || fieldValue.startsWith(filterValue)) {  
                    match = true;  
                }  
                else {  
                    match = false;  
                    break;  
                }  
            } catch(Exception e) {  
                match = false;  
            }   
        }  

        if(match) {  
            data.add(car);  
        }  
    }  

    //sort  
    if(sortField != null) {  
        Collections.sort(data, new LazySorter(sortField, sortOrder));  
    }  

    //rowCount  
    int dataSize = data.size();  
    this.setRowCount(dataSize);  

    //paginate  
    if(dataSize > pageSize) {  
        try {  
            return data.subList(first, first + pageSize);  
        }  
        catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {  
            return data.subList(first, first + (dataSize % pageSize));  
        }  
    }  
    else {  
        return data;  
    }  
}
```

I think that when the method load is called dataSize should be known to call this.setRowCount(dataSize) properly? I think that's the cause of the problem. Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: The dataSize is determined dynamically from the actual data. I have not experienced any problems there, so you might want to look elsewhere. What problems do you have?

Comment: Do you see any error in server console or client side in browser (enable your firebug)? please debug your code and make sure that `setRowCount(dataSize)` is called. and make sure your bean is `@ViewScoped`.

Comment: The problem was with PrimeFaces :(